# C#7 ref return: what stays in memory: the class instance or the ref returned property?

Tags: ref, c#-7.0

```
public ref int GetData()
{
    var myDataStructure = new MyDataStructure();
    return ref myDataStructure.Data;
}

public class MyDataStructure
{
    private int _data;
    public ref int Data => ref _data;
}
```

This uses the new C#7 ref return feature. After GetData() returns, what is kept in memory? The complete MyDataStructure instance? Or only the integer?

If the MyDataStructure instance is kept in memory, because someone is holding a reference to a field of that instance, why can't *s* be kept in memory in this example:

```
public ref string GetString()
{
    string s = "a";
    return ref s; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After GetData() returns, what is kept in memory? The complete MyDataStructure instance? Or only the integer?

The `MyDataStructure` is. It exists on the heap and you have a reference to a field within it.

> why can't *s* be kept in memory in this example

Because while the string on the heap it points to exists on the heap, `s` itself is a local that is not on the heap. As a local, it no longer exists after the method has completed.

Comment: Incidentally. It would have been possible to wrap `s` in something on the heap in at least some such cases, akin to hoisting locals. That though could have been confusing and made some code not only inefficient but inefficient when trying something precisely for the sake of efficiency, so all in all I'm glad they didn't take that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Because `s` is on the stack, winch is lost when the execution of the method finishes.